# Advantages of using Fat Jars over Containers

Tags: java, docker, deployment, jar, containers

I wanna know the difference between the two and also which one is currently used more according to industry standards. I tried finding resources online but the content about Fat Jars is very less and also almost no contrast is shown between the two anywhere.

Comment: Usually you build a fat jar and use it inside a container.

Comment: Could you elaborate over why is it so ? Why can't I just use a fat jar because as far as I know it can be deployed stand alone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems not a big deal at a first glance. The reason for that is that the Java packaging system is really mature and grew strong over many years. Many other ecosystems do not benefit from this and can benefit greatly from being packaged into a container image. But containers are not only about packaging. Packaging could almost be considered a side-effect of it.

Amongst others, some benefits of using containers over simple Fat JARS are:

**Simplified infrastructure**

For a big (or mid-sized) enterprise built around microservices, chances are that not all of them are using the same languages and tools. A container provides a predictable way of deploying all those different things in the same manner, so it greatly simplifies the infrastructure, thus dramatically reducing company costs with it. This becomes even more important when deploying into the cloud, especially in multi-cloud-provider scenarios, and in that case, container orchestration provided by software like Kubernetes help a great deal without much effort.

**Consistency**

Another benefit of containers over regular JARs is consistency across environments. Imagine for instance that you deploy your JAR into DEV (running Java 8) and then into PROD (running Java 10). For some reason the JVM behaves differently, either because of default Garbage Collector or something else, making your program behave differently in both environments. When you deploy through a container image, the same image will be used across different environments, and thus the same Java version will be always used, making it less error-prone.

**Resource isolation**

Yet another benefit is resource isolation. Containers can make sure that your application "see" only a predetermined amount of memory and CPUs. Actually, there were some improvements in Java 10 regarding this matter, you can read more about it [here](https://www.docker.com/blog/improved-docker-container-integration-with-java-10/).

Hope this provides with a better point of view regarding this matter.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the resource isolation point ? How does seeing a predetermined amount of memory and CPU help ?

Comment: Also if you could elaborate more over "provides a predictable way of deploying all those different things in the same manner". Do you mean to say that irrespective of what the container contains they get deployed in the same manner ?

Comment: From an infrastructure management standpoint, CPU usage will help, for example, in cases where multiple containers are run in the same host, ensuring they don't steal CPU from each other. More details [here](https://www.docker.com/blog/cpu-management-docker-1-13/).

Comment: Regarding predictability, it won't matter if a microservice is written using Java, Node.JS, Go or anything else, because the way to run it will always be through a `docker run` (in the case of Docker containers for instance). This represents an advantage for big companies because opens new possibilities for hiring. They don't have to hire only Java experts or force everyone to learn Java, they may use the right tools for specific jobs. As long as a container image comes out of each team, the deployment process can be exactly the same for all of them.

Comment: Of course, it's not a paradise. Containers come with a cost, as soon as start supporting containers, you need container management (tools like Kubernetes), more infrastructure tools to learn. It doesn't always pay. For example, if everything is Java and everyone is ok with that and the deployment process is in place and working fine, you are probably better keeping it. As always, it's a tradeoff.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you can use either standalone fat jars or fat jars inside containers. Key point I'm making is there is no standoff between the two, in fact they are complimentary.

Fat jar is a primary way to wrap java application so it could be easily containerized.

Of course, you could use fat jars in standalone ways too.

*Pros of containerization:*

1. You can take advantage of unified tooling for containers. I.e., you set up docker and you can run any container - be it java with fat jar or node.js or anything else.
2. You can take advantage of various container orchestration systems (docker compose, docker swarm, kubernetes, etc) - meaning you use unified tooling for healthchecks, monitoring, rolling updates, etc.
3. You don't need to worry about things like JRE / JDK versions on your system.

*When you may still want to use standalone:*

- When you have java-centric architecture and established processes around that and it would be costly to change from that to modern container orchestration.
- When you are using java as primary scripting (or application) platform on your instance and simply don't want any overhead of containers.